# WP_Query. Get posts by tag

Tags: wordpress, tags

I need get posts by tag.
I'm using such code for this:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'type' => get_post_type(),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tag'=> $cur_tag
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($args);
?>

<div class="blogs-grid">

    <?php
        $postIndex=0;

    ?>
    <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php
        //some code.....
        $postIndex++;
    ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<div class="pagination blog-pagination">
    <?php
    echo paginate_links( array(/*some param*/) );
    ?>
</div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <!-- no posts found -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

var_dump return such data for tag=blog

> array(5) { ["type"]=> string(8) "blogpost" ["order"]=> string(3)
>   "ASC" ["posts_per_page"]=> int(8) ["paged"]=> int(1) ["tag"]=>
>   string(4) "blog" }

And does not display any records for this tag. In DB present 4 records.

Of course, I could use this code for view posts:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

But on this page I need to display the alaternative number of posts per page and etc.

I can not understand why WP_Query() does not work in my code. Can you help me with it?

What properties should be in array?
My current $args is not working:

```
$args = array(
    'type' => get_post_type(),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tag'=> $cur_tag
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your parameter name is wrong for wp_query arguments.
For post type, you should use 'post_type' not 'type'.
So the correct args should be:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => get_post_type(),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tag'=> $cur_tag
);
```